# Saving screenshot to sandbox

Tags: ios, xcode, screenshot, sandbox

Is there any way to save a screenshot to the application's sandbox or some where that can be easily found to add to an email attachment? currently im saving it in the camera roll but can't seem to be able to get it to attach to my email

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *png = @".png";
NSString *filename = [drawquestion stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@", documentDirectory,filename,png];
NSString *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:link];
NSLog(link);

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, drawquestion, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 bare bones examples of how to attach an image to an email.

```
// with UIImage * image;

  MFMailComposeViewController * mfcvc = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

  NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
  [mfcvc addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"demo"];
  [self.viewController presentModalViewController:mfcvc animated:YES];

// with UIImage * image; and float compression_quality; between 0.0 and 1.0

  MFMailComposeViewController * mfcvc = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

  NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compression_quality);
  [mfcvc addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"demo"];
  [self.viewController presentModalViewController:mfcvc animated:YES];
```

To save the image in the documents directory in the app's sandbox

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *png = @".png";
NSString *filename = [drawquestion stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSString *imagePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",filename, png]];

[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

PS

I cleaned up the construction of the path, it seems your code has a path like

> /var/mobile/Applications/APP_ID//var/mobile/Applications/APP_ID/Documents/filename.png

Comment: Thanks for replying/answering =) erm but how do i go into the camera roll or find it in the app to attach it?

Comment: @Daniel please go further and let me know which one it is.  I looked them up through here http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image/index.html

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand what you use that website for. You have `image.jpeg` as a mime type, shouldn't that be `image/jpeg`

Comment: I got to that page about mime types on the mail composer.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html  Thanks for pointing that out.  They were both wrong. (should be image/png image/jpeg)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out `writeToFile:atomically:` you get your image data, and write it to a file, this will save to the application's sandbox.

Check out this for some example code: http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/05/download-an-image-and-save-it-as-png-or-jpeg-in-iphone-sdk/

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"%@",docDir);

NSLog(@"saving png");
NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.png",docDir];

    // You should swap data for your image data
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
[data writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];
```

You can then use the `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` method on `MFMailComposeViewController` class to attach an attachment (actually you don't even need to save the image to disk):

```
MFMailComposeViewController * mailVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

NSData *data; // this is the data from earlier
[mailVC addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"myfilename"];
[self presentModalViewController:mailVC animated:YES];
```

Be sure to have a correct MIME type set here. The file name you can set to what you want, it is the name of the file in the attachment as seen by the recipient.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer =D how do i find it and attach it to an email?

Comment: updated my answer, you don't actually need to save the image anywhere (camera roll or sandbox inside the app). You can use the image data directly to attach it to the mail.

Comment: hmmm cause its like i have more then one image and i dont know if i should hardcode it or make a for loop to check the amount of images then send it

Comment: You can attach more then one attachment to the mail composer, just watch out for the email size, you know most email service providers have a limit for an email, usually around 10MB. If you have more then one screenshot which is taken throughout the app lifecycle, then you should probably want to save them to the sandbox (my first code). You can get an array of file names from `docDir` or maybe a sub directory and by looping them, load them into an `NSData`, and attach to the email.

Comment: Cool thing, be sure to up vote me if I helped and accept the solution. Thanks.